# border around outside of page but on top of header image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a border around the outside of my page but it needs to be on top of the header image.. I'm not sure how to achieve something like this.

I thought maybe something like

```
body {

    border:solid 1px brown
    padding: 5px;

}
```

But something like this obviously pushing everything in.. Is this even possible to do?

Here's what I'm trying to make: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtVdX.jpg
The brown border just continues around the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a pseudo element purely for stylistic purposes.

Here's some CSS you can try:

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}

body::after {
    border: solid 1px brown;
    padding: 5px;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This should be by default overtop of your body being an "after", you can play around with z-index to achieve your desired effect if not. Hope this helps!